# SSMS Error when creating database “Method not found .. StringCollection”

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

When I try to create a local database in SQL Server Management Studio 2016, I get the following error.

I am creating it through interface by connecting to local machine, right clicking on Databases, and selecting "New Database".

I have no idea what this could possibly indicate?

[image]

I've tried restarting SSMS and the machine.

I can create the database through SQL, however I get the same error when trying to launch any GUI dialogs for the database. So creating it thru SQL doesn't work around my issue as I need to configure it also.

Comment: Can you share what you're doing? Are you creating it via t-sql?

Comment: @Eli I updated question

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to install SSMS 2017 instead. Now it works.